# How to get token prices with UNISWAP API

Tags: python, ethereum, etherscan

I am using uniswap python api to get live token prices. I am using all the variation of the builtin functions. However, it does not give me the right value.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
address = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
private_key =  None
uniswap_wrapper = Uniswap(address, private_key,infura_url,version=2)  
dai = "0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359"


print(uniswap_wrapper.get_eth_token_input_price(dai, 5*10**18))
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_token_eth_input_price(dai, 5*10**18))
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_eth_token_output_price(dai, 5*10**18))
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_token_eth_output_price(dai, 5*10**18))
```

And these are my results respectively,

```
609629848330146249678
24997277527023953
25306950626771242
2676124437498249933489
```

I don't want to use coingecko or coinmarketcaps api as they do not list newly released token prices immediately.

I tried etherscan to get token prices but it does not have a built-in function for that. Does anybody any suggestions on how to fix that or do you know any alternatives?

Comment: Whats the infura_url value you used?   Im having issues querying.

Comment: you need to use yours

Comment: Ah I understand now.  Thank you.   Im also receiving similar values.   Not sure how to convert these to USD prices.

Comment: Hey, @Coni have you ever figured out how to convert the results you get into something meaningful? I am playing with the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time or setup to test this right now, but I believe that what you want is something like this:

```
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_eth_token_input_price(dai, 5*10**18)/5*10**18)
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_token_eth_input_price(dai, 5*10**18)/5*10**18)
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_eth_token_output_price(dai, 5*10**18)/5*10**18)
print(uniswap_wrapper.get_token_eth_output_price(dai, 5*10**18)/5*10**18)
```